# Not Able to Create Multiple Increments in One Loop Based on Conditions

Tags: javascript

Can you pleas etake a look at this demo and let me know why I am not able to create multiple increment in a loop

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 100;) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i < 50) {
    i++;
  }
  if (i > 50) {
    i += 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when `i == 50`, it doesn't get incremented, so it goes into an infinite loop. You need to change one of the conditions to include 50, e.g.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 100;) {
  console.log(i);
  if (i < 50) {
    i++;
  }
  else if (i >= 50) {
    i += 2;
  }
}
```

Note that stack snippets crop the console output, so it appears to be starting at 25 when in fact it will start at 0.

Comment: Thanks Nick but in this case we are missing number `50` which is start point for after 50 listing

Comment: @Behseini the problem was `i` was being incremented twice. I've edited the code to add an `else`...

Comment: Thanks a lost, just one more question? in case of having more conditions! should I add as `if` or `else`?

Comment: @Behseini you should use `else`, otherwise you can run into the issue (as with the original code here) that a previous increment of `i` can make it match one of the next conditions. Either that, or put the conditions in order such that you are comparing against the highest values first e.g. `if (i >= 50) {
    i += 2;
  }
  if (i < 50) {
    i++;
  }` but that is wasteful as you will be executing a lot of tests which are sure to be false. `else` is better.